Custom Plugin not Displaying in the Website Production environment (Divi)
I built a custom plugin for a website Using Divi and I am facing a problem right now getting it to display in the production environment of the website. Here are the details:
Since you can't really add a plugin to a page created with Divi like a module, I had to add my plugin there by downloading another plugin that generates a short code (the plugin's name is Reusable Blocks Extended). I generated the short code and added it to my web page like this: [shortcode] inside the code module. This caused problems because it turns out that a shortcode should actually be added like this: <?php echo do_shortcode("[shortcode]"); ?>. Before making that change, the plugin displayed in the Divi Builder but no changes were saved.
Now the Divi builder is saving changes (albeit, with a piece of the shortcode now showing underneath the plugin), but the display is gone in the production environment. I checked the browser console but there were no errors, none to be found in debug.log either except for errors that relate to deprecated functions in functions.php.
If anyone can spot a missing step or give any recommendations, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!


The plugin in the Divi Builder.



The plugin in the production environment (after exiting the Divi Builder).

The HTML from the browser console:
<div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_4">
    <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_2_3 et_pb_column_9 et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
        <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_heading et_pb_heading_2 et_pb_bg_layout_">   
            <div class="et_pb_heading_container"><h1 class="et_pb_module_heading">News</h1></div>
        </div>
        <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_code et_pb_code_2">
            <div class="et_pb_code_inner">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_3 et_pb_column_10  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et-last-child et_pb_column_empty">
</div>
</div>

